# How do I print a computed score for all input in a file?

Tags: perl, ip, packet

Here is some Perl code which takes two files as input. The files contain TCP packets. It trains itself for the normal packets using the packets in first file and then prints the anomalous packets in the second file.

```
while (<>) {
    if (($time, $to, $port, $from, $duration, $flags, $length, $text) = /(.{19}) (.{15}):(\d+) (.{15}):\d+ \+(\d+) (\S+) (\d+) (.*)/) {
        $text =~ s/\^M//g;
        $text =~ s/\^ /\n/g;
        if (($port == 25 || $port == 80) && $text =~ /\n\n/) {$text = "$`\n";}
        $text =~ s/^\^@//;
        if ($time =~ /(\d\d)\/(\d\d)\/\d\d\d\d (\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d)/) {
            $now = ((($1 * 31 + $2) * 24 + $3) * 60 + $4) * 60 + $5;
        }
        foreach ($text =~ /.*\n/g) {
            if (($k, $v) = /(\S*)(.*)/) {
                $k = substr($k, 0, 30);
                $v = substr($v, 0, 100);
                $score   = 0;
                $comment = "";
                &alarm($port,       $k);
                &alarm($to,         $flags);
                &alarm("To",        "$to:$port");
                &alarm($to,         $from);
                &alarm("$to:$port", $from);
                if ($score > 30000) {
                    $score = log($score) / (10 * log(10));
                    printf("    #   0 $time $to %8.6f \#%s\n", $score, substr($comment, 0, 300));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

sub alarm {
    local ($key, $val, $sc) = @_;
    if ($now < 10300000) {
        ++$n{$key};
        if (++$v{$key . $val} == 1) {
            ++$r{$key};
            $t{$key} = $now;
        }
    } elsif ($n{$key} > 0 && !$v{$key . $val}) {
        $score += ($now - $t{$key}) * $n{$key} / $r{$key};
        $comment .= " $key=$val";
        $t{$key} = $now;
    }
}

exit;
```

I am new to Perl and as a small part my project it needs that anomaly score is to be printed for all the packets in the second file. Can anybody tell how to modify the code?

Comment: Are you asking for help with an algorithm, or just asking how to print a value out?

Comment: I need only the value of score to be printed out for every packet instead of just for some packets....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see here, it looks as if the code (as it is now) looks for packets before some cutoff time, and stores whether or not it has seen certain conditions in the `%n` and `%v` hashes.

Why not give an extra flag to your `alarm` function called `$training`.  If true, just account for the packet values, otherwise, calculate a score for this anomaly (if it is one), and return that value.  If there is no anomaly, or if you're in training mode, just return zero:

```
    sub alarm {
         my ($key, $val, $training) = @_;
         my $score = 0;
         if ( $training ) {
             ...do your accounting...
         } else {
             ...do your comparisons & set score accordingly...
         }
         return $score;
     }
```

Throw your big `while` into a subroutine, and have that subroutine take a filename and whether it is in training mode or not.

```
     sub examine {
         my ($file, $training) = @_;
         if ( open my $fh, '<', $file ) {
             while (<$fh>) {
                 ...this is your big while loop...
                 ...pass $training along to your alarm() calls...
             }
         } else {
             die "Failed to open $file: $!\n';
         }
     }
```

Your main program is now:

```
     use constant TRAINING => 1;

     examine('file1',  TRAINING);
     examine('file2', !TRAINING);
```

More notes:

- Use `my()` instead of `local`, though it doesn't materially affect this program, it's a good habit to get into.
- Don't use a well known function name `alarm` when it really isn't doing anything of the kind, instead name it something like `check_packet_values` -- or something that makes sense to you and your team.
- Stop using magic numbers

  ```
  use constant {
      CUTOFF_TIME   => 10300000,
      ANOMALY_SCORE =>    30000
  };
  ```
- Use a real date/time parser so that your values have some meaning. `str2time` from `Date::Parse` would give you your time in epoch seconds (seconds since Jan 1, 1970).
- Use variable names that mean something.  `%n` and `%v` are hard to understand in this code, but `%n_seen` and `%value_seen` (as well as `%first_seen_time` instead of `%t`).  Remember, your code doesn't run faster if you use shorter variable names.
- Stop using global variables when feasible.  The counters can be global, but your comment should be built only in the routine which is initializing and printing the comment.  So, instead of doing what you are doing, how about:

  ```
  $to_score = check_packet_value($to, $flags)
      and push @comments, "$to=$flags";
  ...
  $score = $to_score + $from_score + ...
  if ( !$training && $score > ANOMALY_THRESHOLD ) {
      print "blah blah blah @comments\n";
  }
  ```
- Also, never, ever use $` -- it causes huge performance penalties in your entire script (even if it never calls this function).  Instead of:

  ```
  if ( $text =~ /\n\n/ ) { $text = $` }
  ```

Use

```
    if ( $text =~ /(.*)\n\n/ ) {
        $text = $1;
    }
```

(Edit: added warning about $`)

Answer (score 0):

I may have misunderstood your question and comment, so forgive me if this isn't what you're asking...

Your printf function currently resides inside this `if ($score > 30000)` check, so you'll only get the output if the `$score` is > 30000.

```
if ($score>30000) {
    $score=log($score)/(10*log(10));
    printf("    #   0 $time $to %8.6f \#%s\n", $score, substr($comment, 0, 300));
}
```

If you want to print the output regardless of the `$score`, you just need to move the printf line outside this if check.

Comment: Two files are given as input to this program and the anomaly score needs to be printed out only for the packets in the second file...

Comment: Ok sorry...  the code is a little hard to understand at first glance, so I'm not sure if I can help you.